# Cannot see user_stats module logs in drupal site

Tags: 7

I have used  User Stats Module for the purpose to find the users login count till date. 
I am able to see the data in database but can't find the logs in my drupal site.

I have checked in "Reports" but can't see. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from some pages available under admin/reports/ip_tracking, which are visible when the Views module is enabled, and the "Track IP addresses" option is enabled on admin/settings/user_stats, the module doesn't show those values. You need to do one of the following:

- Install the [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module
- Use user_stats_get_stats() in a template file

#### Reference

- The [module's README file](http://drupalcode.org/project/user_stats.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt) (Drupal 7)
- The [module's README file](http://drupalcode.org/project/user_stats.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/README.txt) (Drupal 6)